# Translating oracle sql dense rank function to Bigquery

Tags: sql, oracle, function, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble translating a query from Oracle SQL into BigQuery. Below is what I have so far. Any help is appreciated.

oracle version:

```
select
CALL_KEY,
MAX(STATUS) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CUSTOMER_CONTACT DESC) STATUS
```

bigquery versions that I have tried and not gotten to work:

```
select 
CALL_KEY,
#try 1*****************
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MAX(STATUS) ORDER BY ARRAY_AGG(CUSTOMER_CONTACT Limit 1)[Offset(0)] desc ) STATUS

#try 2***************
FIRST_VALUE(STATUS) OVER (PARTITION BY CALL_KEY ORDER BY CUSTOMER_CONTACT desc) STATUS

#try 3*****************
ARRAY_AGG(STATUS ORDER BY CUSTOMER_CONTACT desc)[Offset(0)] STATUS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses arrays:

```
select call_key,
       array_agg(status order by customer_contact desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)]
from t
group by call_key;
```

Comment: that did not work, every value is null except for call key. 
The goal is to get the status based on the first customer_contact value, which is a timestamp field.

Comment: @jhanby . . . Every value of *what*?  This is equivalent to the `keep` syntax in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not %100 clear on input and expected output but, what do you think of add/tune @gordan's answer with `ignore nulls`?

```sql
with calls as (
  select *
    from unnest([struct(1 as call_key, date '2021-06-01' as customer_contact, 'status1' as  status)
                ,struct(1 as call_key, date '2021-06-02' as customer_contact, 'status2' as  status)
                ,struct(1 as call_key, date '2021-06-03' as customer_contact, 'status3' as  status)
                ,struct(2 as call_key, date '2021-06-01' as customer_contact, 'status2' as  status)
                ,struct(2 as call_key, date '2021-06-04' as customer_contact, null as  status)
                ])
)
select call_key
      ,array_agg(status ignore nulls order by customer_contact desc nulls last limit 1)[ordinal(1)] as status
from calls
group by call_key
```

```
+-----+----------+---------+
| Row | call_key | status  |
+-----+----------+---------+
|   1 |        2 | status3 |
|   1 |        2 | status2 |
+-----+----------+---------+
```